# ¿Como puedo utilizar INTERVAL de Postgres con el valor de la columna de una tabla?

Tags: sql, postgresql

INTERVAL por lo general se utiliza de la siguiente manera:

```
select now() + interval '1 month' -> intervalo de tiempo
```

Lo que quiero es enviarle en el intervalo de tiempo, la cantidad de meses a sumar pero con el valor de la columna de una tabla, por ejemplo:

```
tabla.fecha + interval tabla.cantidad_meses 'month'
```

¿Como puedo realizar esto? ya que al ejecutar sale error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es la sintaxis:

```
tabla.fecha + (tabla.cantidad_meses || ' month')::interval
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/AELJL63805)

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfecto.!